# Chrome 64 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Ahh! My site is broken in Chrome.

Getting this message in console: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule`

It points to this line of code, which is from a third-party plugin:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule,0);
```

Stylesheets defined in head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/css/msgPop.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/select2/select2.css">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We believe this commit to Chromium to be the root cause of our issue:

[Update behavior of CSSStyleSheet to match spec for Security origin](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/a4ebe08c91e29140e700c7bae9b94f27a786d1ca)

The quick solution for us was to simply reorder the CSS. It seems that previously the culprit plugin was inserting CSS rules to this remote CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
```

Simply reordering our stylesheets to ensure a script from our site was in first position (`document.styleSheets[0]`), fixed the issue:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/css/msgPop.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Public/js/select2/select2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was adblock playing tricks on me, turn it off and the message should go away
[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! Was having tons of issues debugging this same error and it went away when AdBlock was paused on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically add style tag

```js
class StyleSheet {
  constructor(name = 'dynamic-styleSheet') {
    this.styleSheet = this.getStyleSheet(name)
  }

  getStyleSheet(name) {
    if (!document.getElementById(name)) {
      const style = document.createElement('style')
      style.title = name
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style)
    }

    let styleSheet = null
    for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
      styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i]
      if (styleSheet.title === name) {
        break
      }
    }
    return styleSheet
  }
  insertRule(css, index) {
    return this.styleSheet.insertRule(css, index)
  }
  deleteRule(index) {
    this.styleSheet.deleteRule(index)
  }
}
export default StyleSheet
// let styleSheet = new StyleSheet ()
// styleSheet.insertRule('h1{color:red;}', 0)
```