# Why Chrome cannot access to external stylesheet using insertRule with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML file, and linked in the head, an external stylesheet, and both of them are in the same folder. There are only one stylesheet. In the bottom of the body, i have a script:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".example{position: relative}", 0);
```

But i get this error message (suprisingly only on Chrome 64, on FireFox, Safari mobile and Chrome mobile works well):

**`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule`**

Why?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - doesn't apply any longer (that was from 4 yrs ago)

Comment: Have you checked your existing stylesheets to ensure that they are error-free? https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: @RandyCasburn i simply linked a similar answer that may help ;) i never said it apply ... if it was the case i would have closed it as a duplicate :)

Comment: Is the stylesheet from the same origin?  If not, that is what one can expect from Chrome going forward for everything.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - OK - but it is a complete different error message :-/

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Yes i checked it, shown 2 errors, fixed it, but the problem still exists.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - I have a folder, in the folder are some images, a css file, and the html file.

Comment: Right - thanks for the edit, I saw that after.

Comment: Please look at this plunker - it works fine for me. Does it for you? http://plnkr.co/edit/fztsSahELEkVHtQHpLXv?p=preview

Comment: Yes, works fine for me too. The white color is applied.

Comment: Do you have any @ rules in your stylesheet?

Comment: @RandyCasburn - Yes, i have some media rules. Very weird, but i tried the plunker in Chrome, applied exactly the same html and css what i have, and that way, it works. So i really don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome 64 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756451/chrome-64-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-insertrule-on-cssstyleshee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the index for your insert. In CSS files all @ Rules must be at the top of the file.  So, if you have 4 @ rules at the top of the CSS file, change the index to 4 thus:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".example{position: relative}", 4);
```

That should work.

Here is the spec reference (see the note):

https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#insert-a-css-rule

Comment: I tried this solution, but with changing the order of the rules, the things get out of control. But i tried not to add a rule to the stylesheet, but only read it. I used this code:
`example.innerHTML = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText`, and get the following error:
**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules**

Comment: Bummer - We know from the earlier Plunker that it works correctly with a simple model. It seems we've isolated this down to your stylesheet. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I tried with a very simple version. Looks like, the problem is with my Chrome.
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>asd</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h2>This</h2>
    <script>
        document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("h2{color: white}",0)
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
The CSS:
`h2{background-color: aqua}`
Same error:
*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule*
But i tried, it works with internal stylesheet in the head.

Comment: @GergőHorváth   I know this might sound odd, but please add a title attribute with a string to the `<link>` element and attempt your simple use case again.

Comment: @GergőHorváth - and finally, you might try setting a CSP meta tag like this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self' 'unsafe-eval'">'

Comment: @GergőHorváth - what version and build of Chrome are you using?

Comment: After a long-time research, i realized that the problem is with the CORS same origin policy, the external stylesheet needed to be origin-clean flagged. I don't understand these things, so i choose the easier way, put an internal stylesheet to the head. Works fine.

Comment: Glad you found that out - it happened to be my second question in the comments to your question. You probably blew it off because you didn't understand the question. It would have saved you a lot of time to ask for clarification - we would have solved it together yesterday :-)

Comment: The html file and the css file is from the same origin, but both of them in a folder that is on my computer. And i search for the solution, but i read that it's very difficult to gain the origin-clean flag this way. Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Not a waste of time. How are you opening the HTML file? I think I asked this earlier as well. What does the address bar say? http://, https://, file://, etc.

Comment: Across localhost with http:// and directly open the HTML file within the folder, with file://.

Comment: that's the CORS problem. Anytime you want to load a URL from a web page that is loaded from the file system with the "file" protocol ( file:// ) the origin of that document is "null". So even loading a resource from http://localhost (the same machine) is a different origin. If you have python: open a shell or command prompt in the folder where the HTML file is and execute: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`; in your browser go to `http://localhost:8000/nameofhtmlfile.html` and everything will work as you expect.