# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got the following error when I was working on a project: "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'addRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access StyleSheet to insertRule"

Could someone help me fix my code, because I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

The head of my HTML document:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plunder Data Research and Analysis</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+JP&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

The line of JavaScript code that is giving the error:

```
styleSheet.addRule(".new-plunder-form-username:focus {border: 1.5px solid #75b4d9; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #75b4d9;}");
```

The styleSheet constant:

```
const styleSheet = document.styleSheets[0];
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756451/chrome-64-uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-insertrule-on-cssstyleshee) similar question on Stack Overflow, but my stylesheets as you can see are already ordered with the stylesheet I'm trying to access first like it said to do.

Comment: Make sure that `styleSheet` points to the correct style sheet by looking at its properties. You may find that it's pointing to the one from googleapis.com.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Do you mean that `document.styleSheets` may not be in the order that the CSS is declared in the markup?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just logged styleSheet to the console and checked its properties, and it is the correct stylesheet.

Comment: I mean there are a few reasons that `document.styleSheets[0]` would not refer to what you think it should refer to. Better just to debug. Also, if the HTML is not exactly the same as what is shown here, let us know. The error you've shown is typically only thrown when the style sheet is loaded from a different origin.

Comment: This is exactly how the entire head of my HTML looks. If you want more of the HTML though, I can add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the `styles.css` exists on your server. If it doesn't, that might be causing it to be inaccessible.

Worst-case, you could create and insert another stylesheet.

```
const styleSheet = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
styleSheet.textContent = ".new-plunder-form-username:focus {border: 1.5px solid #75b4d9; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #75b4d9;}";
```

Comment: styles.css is in my project folder, and I'm not running a server, so it should work. Thanks for the idea! I'll probably do that if I don't get another answer that works.